# How to apply more than one function to a passed in live template variable?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, live-templates

I'm trying to build a Python Unit Test File Template in PyCharm. The overall result I want to achieve is:

1. A user creates a new file with my template, say "`widget_builder.py`"
2. Inside the template I want to create the class name by taking the file name "`widget_builder`" and turning it into "`WidgetBuilderTests`"

It looks like I need to use a Live Template to manipulate the file template variable `$FILE_NAME$`?

How can I create a Live Template that given a passed in variable (in this case `$FILE_NAME$`), applies both the `underscoresToCamelCase` and `capitalize` functions to it?

If I declare the Template text as:

```
$CLASS_NAME$
```

...and then edit variables, how can I reference a passed in variable of '$FILE_NAME$'?

I'd imagine it to look something like this, but I just can't get it to work:

[image: Example]

I'm sure there must be a way to do this, but I just can't quite wrap my head round it.

Is this possible? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I've got a bit further. If I define the template as this:

[image]

If I then use it, this happens:

[image]

So the end result of `$CLASS_NAME$` (`WidgetBuilder`) on the left is what I want, but I don't want `$FILE_NAME$` (`widget_builder`) to be there once I hit return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem here is that `$FILE_NAME$` is not a native variable in the live templates, merely an arbitrary name. What you actually want to be using is another function: `fileNameWithoutExtension()`.

So your template would look something like:
[image]

Comment: Thank - that worked nicely! I can't get it to work inside a File Template, but I'll ask that on a separate question.