# PyCharm: How to use Live Template in File Template

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, live-templates, file-templates

This question follows on from one I asked last week - [How to apply more than one function to a passed in live template variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660195/how-to-apply-more-than-one-function-to-a-passed-in-live-template-variable/39667591#39667591)

Now that I have a live template function called `classNameFromFileName`, I am unable to use it in a file template.

I have ticked the "Enable Live Templates" checkbox inside the File Template editor page and no combination of `#set` or `#[[ ]]#` etc will work.

If I use the template, it just ends up putting the name of the Live Template function inside my new file, rather than actually calling the function.

The PyCharm help offers nothing in the way of an example - does anyone know how to call a live template function from a file template?

Thanks.

Comment: I may need to contact JetBrains directly and ask them to put some examples on their help site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now it's not possible. You can vote for these issues:

- [Live template variables don't work properly in File templates](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-159930)
- [Code Templates. Add ability to use Live Templates or Live Template variables.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161937)